# Need to put a grid for 10000 records on mobile using MVC.net 4

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have JSON for 100,000 records. I need to show this in a mobile.
I have 2 options:

1. Load the complete JSON once and then use jQuery  mobile grid to render it
2. Using MVc4.net to fetch 20 records first and then load subsequent records using paging.

Please suggest me which approach will be best as the performance is the main parameter in my case. In first case initial load time will be slower but subsequent paging will be faster but in second case more server interactions will happen.

Comment: Well, you could always do an inital load of 20 records, then perform an AJAX call to retrieve the rest of the records while the user is doing their thing.

Comment: Thanks Scottie for replying..so as per you client side rendering will be better option

Comment: How much data is in the 10,000 records?  Have you timed it to see how long it takes to load the whole data set?  Personally, I'd probably do fetches of small amounts of data rather than load the entire dataset.  But, of course, do you business needs say that if they travel out of range, the data should still be available?